# How to await call to a Web service and deliver answer to multiple source in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function that fetch data from a database and if there is no data it will call a Web Service , put the answer in the databse and return the answer.

In order to avoid multiple call to the Web Service I want if there is multiple call to the function while a call to the Web Service is still running, every call after the first one wait for the answer of the first call without calling the Web Service.

How can I achieve this ?

Sample of the code I have :

```
Future<String> function() async {
    String data = await database.getData();
    if (data == null) {
        data = await callWebService();
        await database.setData(data);
    }
    return data
}
```

If this matter, I use Chopper for the Web service call, and Mobx to manage the state of my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [completer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html) to achieve what you want
Check the sample code below.

```
class TestService {
  Completer<String> _completer;

  Future<String> function() async {
    if (_completer == null) {
      _completer = Completer<String>();
    } else {
      return _completer.future;
    }

    String data = await database.getData();
    if (data == null) {
      data = await callWebService();
      await database.setData(data);
    }
    _completer.complete(data);
    _completer = null;
    return data;
  }
}
```